# Any way to know when a variable has been closed over?

Tags: c#, lambda, closures

So closures in C# are awesome, and expressive and great. Except when they aren't (in particular when you don't mean to close a value over). Are there any tricks, (programming or IDE) to determine when a variable has been closed over?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are there any tricks, (programming or IDE) to determine when a variable has been closed over?

Some tooling, such as Resharper, will provide warnings when a variable is being closed over in specific ways, in order to prevent certain errors.